# How can I rename a file in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement a file upload form using angular and node. The files upload fine, but I want to scan the upload directory to see if the filename already exists. If so, then the file would be renamed. Here is what I have so far:

```
app.post('/file', function(req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var file = req.files.file;

    // destination directory
    var dest_dir = './uploads;
    var filename = file.name;

    // THIS ISN'T WORKING, I.E., THE FILE IS NOT RENAMED
    fs.readdir(dest_dir, function(err, dir_files) {
        for(var i = 0; i < dir_files.length; i++) {
            if(dir_files[i] == filename) {
                console.log("I can see this message, but the file isn't renamed");
                filename = filename + '_1'; // rename the file
            }
        }
    });

    // read file from temp dir and store in permanent dir
    var source = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(dest_dir + '/' + filename);
    source.pipe(dest);

    source.on('end', function() { res.json("File has been uploaded!") });
    source.on('error', function(err) { res.json("There was an error when attempting to upload this file.") });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [fs.rename()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) for renaming files in node.

Answer (score 0):

fs.readDir() is asynchronous, so the code below is executed before the **for** loop inside fs.readDir()'s callback:

```
var dest = fs.createWriteStream(dest_dir + '/' + filename);
source.pipe(dest);
```

You need to put this code inside the callback if you want to execute after the **for** loop.  Here is the change:

```
app.post('/file', function(req, res) {
var fs = require('fs');
var file = req.files.file;
var source = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
var dest;

// destination directory
var dest_dir = './uploads;
var filename = file.name;

fs.readdir(dest_dir, function(err, dir_files) {
    for(var i = 0; i < dir_files.length; i++) {
        if(dir_files[i] == filename) {
            console.log("I can see this message, but the file isn't renamed");
            filename = filename + '_1'; // rename the file
            break;
        }
    }

    dest = fs.createWriteStream(dest_dir + '/' + filename);
    source.pipe(dest);

 });
 source.on('end', function() { res.json("File has been uploaded!") });
 source.on('error', function(err) { res.json("There was an error when attempting to upload this file.") });
```

});